# How to create try counter in C?

Tags: c

So, I've just started to learn C. I decided to make a basic number guessing game, where it tells you if you were too high or too low, and gives you up to 5 tries. I've got it working, but I can't figure out how to do the 5 tries. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = ( rand() % 10 ) + 1; /* generates "random" number */
        int number;
        int c = 0;
        printf( "Guess a number from one to ten!\n" );
        do {
                scanf( "%d", &number);
                if (number == r) {
                        printf( "Correct! You win!!!\n" );
                        c = 1; /* ends loop if correct */
                }   
                else if (number > r) {
                        printf( "Too high! Try again!\n" );
                }   
                else {
                        printf( "Too low! Try again!\n" );
                }           
        }   
        while ( c == 0 );
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to count the number of times `while` looped. So where do you think it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a counter to your loop condition:

```
int counter = 0;

do {
....
counter++;
}   
while ( c == 0 && counter < 5 );
```

Comment: Ended up using a variation of this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change `c == 0` to `c != 5`.  Everytime they guess incorrect increment c by 1. Also if they guess correctly either do `c = 5` or use the keyword `break` to break out of the do-while loop. You are quite close though.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a loop outside the origin loop in your program.

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{ ...
  if (number=r)
  {  printf("you win.");
     return 0;
  }
  else if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferably, do like this, for best readability:

```
const int MAX = 5;
bool found = false;

for(int tries=0; !found && tries<MAX; tries++)
{
  scanf( "%d", &number);
  if (number < r)
  {
    // ...
  }
  else if(number > r)
  {
    // ...
  }
  else // number == r
  {  
    found = true;
  }
}

if(found)
{
  // ...
}
else
{
  // ...
}
```

As a rule of thumb, always use a `for` loop when the number of iterations are known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mainteining your `do while` loop you can do

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

#define MAX_TRY 5
int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = ( rand() % 10 ) + 1; /* generates "random" number */
        int number;
        int c = 0;
        printf( "Guess a number from one to ten!\n" );
        do 
        {
                scanf( "%d", &number);

                // Count the new inserted value
                c++;

                if (number > r) 
                {
                        printf( "Too high! Try again!\n" );
                }
                else if (number < r)
                {
                        printf( "Too low! Try again!\n" );
                }
                else
                {
                        printf( "Correct! You win!!!\n" );
                        c = MAX_TRY; /* ends loop if correct */
                }
        }
        while ( c < MAX_TRY );

        return 0;
}
```

As you can see

1. I changed the `while` condition to check that max tries are as stated.
2. I inverted your `if-else` sequence to make the loop able to exit
   immediately after the correct value is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I defined another variable `int n=0` and used it just before your conditional sentence starts and in loop I used `and` operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = ( rand() % 10 ) + 1; /* generates "random" number */
        int number;
        int c = 0,n=0; /* new int variable defined */
        printf( "Guess a number from one to ten!\n" );
        do {
                n+=1;
                scanf( "%d", &number);
                if (number == r) {
                        printf( "Correct! You win!!!\n" );
                        c = 1; /* ends loop if correct */
                }
                else if (number > r) {
                        printf( "Too high! Try again!\n" );
                }
                else {
                        printf( "Too low! Try again!\n" );
                }
        }
        while ( c == 0 && n != 5);
        return 0;
}
```

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = ( rand() % 10 ) + 1; /* generates "random" number */
    int number;
    int c = 0; /* new int variable defined */
    printf( "Guess a number from one to ten!\n" );
    do {
            c+=1;
            scanf( "%d", &number);
            if (number == r) {
                    printf( "Correct! You win!!!\n" );
                    break;
            }
            else if (number > r) {
                    printf( "Too high! Try again!\n" );
            }
            else {
                    printf( "Too low! Try again!\n" );
            }
    } while ( c<5);

    if(c==5)
    printf("You lose\n");
 return 0;
}
```